# Is it bad if millions of files are stored in one NTFS folder?

Tags: windows, performance, ntfs, io

I have a very large NTFS volume with more than 20TB capacity and containing millions of files. If I put all of the files in the same folder, I know the performance is bad when I open the folder in Windows Explorer.

Is the performance still bad if I open one of the files directly in my program?

Answer (score 6):

If you are opening the file directly there's no matter how many of files you got in there. but if you are using TAB auto-complete to access file faster it will definitely affect the performance.

I found some clues in here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197162/ntfs-performance-and-large-volumes-of-files-and-directories

> To answer your question more directly: If you're looking at 100K
>   entries, no worries. Go knock yourself out. If you're looking at tens
>   of millions of entries, then either:
>
> a) Make plans to sub-divide them into sub-folders (e.g., lets say you
>   have 100M files. It's better to store them in 1000 folders so that you
>   only have 100,000 files per folder than to store them into 1 big
>   folder. This will create 1000 folder indices instead of a single big
>   one that's more likely to hit the max # of fragments limit or
>
> b) Make plans to run contig.exe on a regular basis to keep your big
>   folder's index defragmented.
>
> Read below only if you're bored.
>
> The actual limit isn't on the # of fragment, but on the number of
>   records of the data segment that stores the pointers to the fragment.
>
> So what you have is a data segment that stores pointers to the
>   fragments of the directory data. The directory data stores information
>   about the sub-directories & sub-files that the directory supposedly
>   stored. Actually, a directory doesn't "store" anything. It's just a
>   tracking and presentation feature that presents the illusion of
>   hierarchy to the user since the storage medium itself is linear.